# Xamarin.Forms Naxam Mapbox Getting Error When Deploying To Android 11

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have a Xamarin Forms project that i have included the Naxam Mapbox project into .
I am able to display the map on all versions of Android before version 11.
When i deploy to a device that has Android 11 i get the following error:

```
Java.Lang.SecurityException: 'getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber'
```

On this Method:

```
public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

            MapView = view as MapView;
        }
```

which is found in the class MapViewFragment of the Naxam.Mapbox.Platform.Droid.

What i have tried is:

1. updating all my Projects to Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.1874.
2. Migrating The Naxam.Mapbox Droid project to AndroidX.
3. Installing Naxam.Mapbox.Services.Android.Telemetry version 5. on The Xamarin Project Android and             Naxam Project Android
4. Installed Naxam.MapBox Droid version 9.0.1 On Xamarin Project Android version 8.4.0 On Naxam Project Droid.
5. Installed Xamarin.Build.Download 0.10.0 on all projects.

If anyone could please point me in the right direction i would really appreciate it.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-android/issues/425

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downgrading the Android target version to 10. If your application does not use Android 11 features, then this is not a bad temporary solution.